# Get customer id from session null

Tags: magento2, product, php, customer-account

I tried to get customer id from `default.phtml` in `/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type`, but when I use `$_SESSION['customer_base']`, the customer_id is NULL like in the picture below. How can I get the current logged in customer id ?

[image]

Comment: Please share your code so get more idea.

Comment: Check https://ranasohel.me/2017/05/05/how-to-get-customer-id-from-block-when-full-page-cache-enable-in-magento-2/

Comment: Have you checked this one? [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178423/magento-2-get-customer-id-of-logged-in-user-with-cache-enabled)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
  echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
....

protected $_customerSessionFactory;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory,
    .....
    .....
) {
    .....
    $this->_customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
    .....
    .....
}

....
....

$customerSession = $this->_customerSessionFactory->create();
$customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();
```

Comment: I can get ID in controller by this but it returns nothing in model class, cache is disabled

Comment: Check my updated code