# Magento 2 : Add product to comapre using product ID programetically

Tags: magento2

I need to add a product to compare using a product id in Magento2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code :

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$compare = $objectManager->create('Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\ComparedFactory');

$productids = [1001,1002, 1003, 1004]; // put your order id which you want to add in compare list.
    $customerid = 114;  // put customer id
     foreach ($productids as $productid) {
        $compareitem->setCustomerId($customerid);
        $compareitem->addProductData($productid);
        $compareitem->save();
        $compareitem->unsetData();

        $viewdata = [
            'product_id' => $productid,
            'customer_id' => $customerid
        ];
        $compare->setData($viewdata)->save();
        echo $productid.' added compare with customer id - '.$customerid;
    }
?>
```

Comment: How to use this code root of Magento in external file?

Comment: Really great support.

Comment: In my Magento root file working fine.

Comment: can i use this code in custom.phtml file same to use object manager without customer login add in current session same as like click to add compare.

My requirement is I list all related product in custom phtml file and need to add relate product all in compare list in single click of submit

Comment: can i use this code in custom.phtml file same to use object manager without customer login - yes you can...:)

Comment: but here you mention customer id?How to use this in add to compare in curreent session?
without login customer?

Comment: to check here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198158/get-customer-id-from-session-null?rq=1 how to get customer id.

Comment: without login how to add product in compare list?

Comment: try to do with customer id set is null