# Magento 2.2.3 Which is the right way to get logged Customer?

Tags: customer, login, magento2.2.3

I want to check if a customer is logged or not. And if he/she logged, I want to get the customerId. I just googled but I could find 2 ways.
One is to use CustomerSession:
`Magento\Customer\Model\Session`
Another one is to use Customer\Model\Context.
`Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH`

Which is right way?
These 2 articles show different way. I am really confusing what I should use.
http://www.blogtreat.com/get-logged-in-customer-data-in-magento-2/

[Magento 2: get customer id of logged in user with cache enabled](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178423/magento-2-get-customer-id-of-logged-in-user-with-cache-enabled)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try Following Way..

In Magento 2 we can check Customer is logged in or not by below way,
Using Block file, Pass **Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context** as a dependency to construct method.

```
    <?php
    namespace Rakesh\Customer\Block;

    class Customerinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }
        /*
         * return bool
         */
        public function getLogin() {
            return $this->httpContext->isLoggedIn();
        }
    ?>
```

Call **getLogin** function in template file,

```
$isLoggedin = $block->getLogin();
if($isLoggedin) {
    // show your message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use dependency injection into your .phtml files.
I'll leave you an example of how to check it in a Helper class.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;    

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

public function isLoggedIn(){
            $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
            return $isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

Then you can call this in your phtml in order to obtain the value:

```
$myhelper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data'); 
$isloggedin = $myhelper->isLoggedIn();
```