# How to get Logged in Customer ID

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

i am trying to get customer id of a logged in customer but its does not seems to be working

**in my block**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;

class Rfq extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_customerSession;    
    public function __construct(Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
 
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;   
    }

            public function getCustomerId()
                    {
                         if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
                              return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();                        
                         endif;
                    }

            public function execute()
            {

                $this->_view->loadLayout();
                $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
                $this->_view->renderLayout();
            }
        }
```

**Now in phtml file**

```
<?php
$customerId = $customer->getCustomerId();
?>
```

**any suggestion or issue in code**
thankss

Update controller

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
        $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
    }


  
}
```

Comment: with full page cache enabled you might have problems using session data, another option is to make an ajax call to get the customer id. A similar question and answers is here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178423/magento-2-get-customer-id-of-logged-in-user-with-cache-enabled/178427

Comment: please share your block file full code

Comment: ok done please check

Comment: please check updated answer and update me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot customer id at your block class when your page hit at full page cache.

You have to pass the **customer id** as an ***HTTP context*** variable.

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#configure-page-variations

Create a [**plugin**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)  class on `Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
        <plugin name="add_customr_id_full_page"  disabled="false" sortOrder="20"
                type="Devamitbera\Module\Plugin\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction"/>        
    </type>   

    </type>      
</config>
```

**On plugin pass current customer id as  http context variable:**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Devamitbera\Module\Plugin\Framework\App\Action;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context as CustomerContext;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class AbstractAction
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }
    

    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {

        $customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId();
        $this->httpContext->setValue(
            'current_cust_id',
            $customerId,
            0
        );

        return $proceed($request);
    }
}
```

After that Inject, `\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context` on your block class  and get this customer id value by  `$this->httpContext->getValue('current_cust_id')`

Comment: exactly this is the only way thankss a lot

Comment: I wish this answer was slightly more detailed, it is not super clear how to actually use this in a custom module. Oh sweet lord I hate working with Magento, why is getting something so simple and commonly required as the customer ID so flipping convoluted ... Why can you get the customer group but not the ID?? 

Answer (score 1):

Your block code need to like this one:

```
public function getCustomerId()
{
     if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
          return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();                        
     }
}
```

And in phtml you need to call like this one :

```
<?php $customerId = $block->getCustomerId(); ?>
```

Comment: will it work even when the cache is enabled?

Comment: Yes, you can try

Comment: yes fpc issue is there it giving the same customer id even the customer has logged out

Comment: But according to code, it will not going into if, because the customer is not login.

Comment: even though customer is logged in still not working

Comment: Have you check into private browser mode one's? And any block on that page which set cacheble="false" ?

Comment: yes my code is working properly when fpc is disable but disabling is not recomended am looking for an alternate here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112766/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-chikku).

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is perfect.I am assuming your block file call in your **`.xml`** file and in xml file call **`.phtml`** file.And you run below all commands like :-

```
remove your var/cache
remove your var/view_preprocessed
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

After you check your output.And Again not show your output check your log error share with me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: i have already tried

Answer (score 0):

In Block file you need to change code as below

**From:**

```
<?php
$customerId = $customer->getCustomerId();
?>
```

**To:**

```
<?php
$customerId = $block->getCustomerId();
?>
```

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

> **Use this into you layout file where you add your block.**

> **cacheable="false"**

```
        <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\BlockName"
               name="block_index_edit"
               template="VendoreName_ModuleName::edit.phtml"
               cacheable="false" />
```

***Update***

> **Your Controller File**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
        $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
    }
}
```

> **Your Block File**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Rfq extends Template
{
    protected $request;
    protected $sessionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $sessionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->sessionFactory = $sessionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        // get customer id here
        $customerSession = $this->sessionFactory->create();
        return $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    }

}
```

> **Your phtml file**

```
<?php
$customerId = $block->getCustomerId();
echo "Customer ID is ".$customerId;
?>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: this will disable caching for all pages and which i dont want

Comment: please share your controller block and phtml file i will give you second way to get customer id.

Comment: block and phtml is already there wait am sharing controller

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in E:\xampp\htdocs\m2\app\code\vedor\module\Controller\Index\Customer.php on line 33

Comment: it's semicolon error in $this->blockName->setCustomerId($cust_id); don't forget to run upgrade command before check

Comment: sorry i didnt notice that

Comment: please check and update me @Chikku

Comment: Hi @Msquare for every customer the id is 0 i think this is the reason here  protected $cust_id = 0;

Comment: just replace this  protected $cust_id = 0; to $cust_id;

Comment: checked already am getting blank with echo text in phtml file

Comment: please try this above code, if not get customer id then you must be use cacheable="false" for get customer id.

Comment: no problem i will find some solution for it thank you for your effort and i dont know who downvoted the ans guyzz do not do that try to understand someones effort between upvoted for the effort thanks

Answer (score 0):

If customer is logged in then you can't get From Session Try this way

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $customerContext,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customer
{
    $this->customer           = $customer;
    $this->customerContext        = $customerContext;
}

public function getCustomerID()
{
    $customerLoggedIn= $this->customerContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
    if($customerLoggedIn){
        $customerId = $this->customer->create()->getCustomer()->getId();
        return $customerId;
    }
}
```